# Doxygen: multiple use of section label while adding anchor

Tags: c++, doxygen

I get the following warning from Doxygen 1.8.11

warning: multiple use of section label 'anchor_computePointMap_' while adding anchor, (first occurrence: /home/meir/Dropbox/CurrentWork/Development/SearchLib/core/user_interface/drawer.h, line 219)

As far as I can tell, the anchor is defined only once (at the line cited by the warning):

```
/// @{
/// \anchor anchor_computePointMap_
/// \name Computing the layout.
/// ...
template <class State> HasNoLayout<State> computePointMap_() {
    ...
}

template <class State> HasLayout<State> computePointMap_() {
    ...
}
/// @}
```

The warning remains even if I rename the anchor and don't reference it. The file is part of a header-only library. I tried to put the header containing the section through Doxygen on its own and it passed without a warning. I looked at the output of the pre-processor and the commented definitions appear only once, so the pre-processor guards work properly. Any ideas what else could go wrong?

Comment: @BoPersson They are used in SFINAE. The code compiles and runs.

Comment: Is the option `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` enabled? If so the comment will be duplicated for each item in the group, which can explain the double anchor.

Comment: @doxygen No, my configuration file has `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO`